# RapidClipse and PMD plugin

Tags: pmd, rapidclipse

How can i install a working PMD plugin in RapidClipse 10.4. I allready tried the 2 plugins from the marketplace but none was able to automatically run after saving a file.

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to activate PMD-nature in my eclipse-project. then everything works as expected.